# comparing two strings in python with duplicates

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the two strings: 'apple' and 'pear' and return letters that do not belong to the other string.

For example, 'apple' does not contain 'r' in 'pear'

'pear' does not contain 'l' and 'p' in apple (pear contains p but does not contains two p's).

So I want to have a function that returns 'r', 'l', and 'p'.

I tried set, but it ignores the duplicates (p, in this example).

```
def solution(A, B):
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    letters_not_in_B = list(set([c for c in A if c not in B]))
    letters_not_in_A = list(set([c for c in B if c not in A]))
    answer = len(letters_not_in_B) + len(letters_not_in_A)
    return answer
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: chris. I just did.

Comment: If you want duplicates, than you shouldn't use sets since they only have unique values, just use lists

Comment: You say you want the function to return 'r', 'l', and 'p' but your attempt, *after having letters*, instead returns a *number*. Make up your mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare the character counts for each separate string resulting from the concatenation of the parameters `a` and `b`:

```
def get_results(a, b):
  return list(set([i for i in a+b if a.count(i) != b.count(i)]))

print(get_results('apple', 'pear'))
```

Output:

```
['p', 'r', 'l']
```

Comment: This returns identical results for `get_results('apppppple', 'pear')`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @JohnGordon the OP wants data formatted with no duplicates where there occurs a letter that does not have equal counts in each string.

Comment: I interpret "return letters that do not belong to the other string" as meaning "If the first string has one `p` and the second string has five `p`s, I want four `p`s returned."  Shame on OP for not being precise, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
Counter('apple') - Counter('pear') # --> Counter({'p': 1, 'l': 1})
Counter('pear') - Counter('apple') # --> Counter({'r': 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(a, b):

    # create mutable list copies of a and b
    list_a = list(a)
    list_b = list(b)

    for ch in a:
        if ch in list_b:
            list_b.remove(ch)

    for ch in b:
        if ch in list_a:
            list_a.remove(ch)

    return list_a + list_b
```